# Catching exception of ApiController in Ninject Interceptor

Tags: asp.net, ninject, asp.net-web-api, interception

Hi i have a problem with exception handling in ApiController.

I have Ninject interceptor bound to Controller actions the problem is that interceptor never sees any exception that was thrown in/bellow Controller.

```
public class ControllerInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        private DbContextTransaction transaction;

        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            try
            {
                invocation.Proceed() // action will throw exception for sure
            }
            catch (Exception) // never executes even if there was exception in Proceed
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

My only idea is that ApiController catches all exceptions and never forwards them up so for interceptor everything looks like nothing happend. Can anyone confirm that.

Comment: have you checked (debugged) that the interceptor is ever called? If so, yes, then the implementation or another interceptor is catching all exceptions.

Comment: Yes there is another interceptor in services layer (below controller) but it's catch looks like

try{} catch {throw;}

interceptor is being called for sure btw becouse try and finally block executes.

I went as far as to make controller get method throw exception and it exectues whole try block (every instruction before and after invocation.Proceed) not seeing any exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem.
I used Ninject.Extensions.Interception with Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Linfu.
Resolved making the action method virtual.